# How do i send multiple arguments to an Express.js route?

Tags: node.js, express

Let say I want to add multiple arguments.

Here's the code

```
function firstArgument(req, res, next) {
    // Do something
}

function secondArgument(req, res, next) {
    // Do something
}


app.get('/something', firstArgument, secondArgument, function(req, res, next) {
// Is it possible to do this?
});
```

Is it possible? if so how does it works? Can anyone explain it to me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are in the express docs - http://expressjs.com/es/guide/routing.html

To summarize, for your scenario you can use:

```
var cb0 = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('CB0')
  next()
}

var cb1 = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('CB1')
  next()
}

app.get('/example/d', [cb0, cb1], function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('response will be sent by the next function ...')
  next()
}, function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello from D!')
})
```

or, without the second method.

```
   var cb0 = function (req, res, next) {
      console.log('CB0')
      next()
    }

    var cb1 = function (req, res, next) {
      console.log('CB1')
      next()
    }

    app.get('/example/d', [cb0, cb1], function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello from D!')
    })
```

Regarding how it works - it simply runs all the methods one after the other: when the next() method is called, the next method is being called.

Comment: The second argument to `app.get()` doesn't even have to be an array.